# Upgrade from 3.1.0 to 4.0.0 throws NoSuchMethod for org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.put(Ljava/lang/Object;)

Tags: apache-poi, xmlbeans, apache-poi-4

Upgraded `XMLBeans` from `3.1.0` to `4.0.0` and it throws a `NoSuchMethodError exception` for

> org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.put(Ljava/lang/Object;)

when open is called.

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.put(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable.<clinit>(SharedStringsTable.java:94)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFReader.getSharedStringsTable(XSSFReader.java:115)
    at com.monitorjbl.xlsx.impl.StreamingWorkbookReader.init(StreamingWorkbookReader.java:122)
    at com.monitorjbl.xlsx.impl.StreamingWorkbookReader.init(StreamingWorkbookReader.java:91)
    at com.monitorjbl.xlsx.StreamingReader$Builder.open(StreamingReader.java:251)
    at xx.xxxx.xxxxx.imports.excel.ExcelImportParser.importStream(ExcelImportParser.java:34)
```

My code:

```
public ImportResult<ImportXmlNode> importStream(int year, InputStream excelStream)  {

    ImportXmlNode root = new ImportXmlNode(null, "", 0);

    try {

        Workbook wb = StreamingReader.builder()
                .rowCacheSize(100)
                .bufferSize(4096)
                .open(excelStream); <------

        ExcelStreamer excelStreamer = new ExcelStreamer(wb);

        ...
```

What am i missing?

TIA

Comment: Should i provide a xml sample?

Comment: You need to wait for POI 5.0.0 to be released, before updating to XmlBeans 4.0.0. I've refactored XmlOptions accessors and a lot of other deprecated constructs.

Comment: Same issue in POI 5.0.0 too